# "por mucho tiempo" or "para mucho tiempo"?

Tags: preposiciones

According to the fact that we use "por" for the time discussions, for example:

> for the time being => por el momento.

But could we sometimes use "para" in this context?! for example:

> El Real Zaragoza tiene cantera para mucho tiempo.

So in consequence, which one is correct? "Por" or "Para"?

Comment: For your second example I would have said _hace mucho tiempo_ but I will leave it to one of the Spanish speakers to elucidate.

Comment: @mdewey it has a different meaning: it means that Real Zaragoza has a good future based on their 'cantera'. It is like saying 'tenemos abuelo para mucho tiempo' when we talk about a healthy grandpa that we expect to live many years

Comment: @mdewey what fedorqui said, and: if you want to talk about the past, you would need to use "El Real Zaragoza tiene cantera **desde hace** mucho tiempo", as "hace mucho tiempo" means "a long time ago", and "desde hace mucho tiempo" means "for a long time" (in the past).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of "**por**" and "**para**" with durations has very different meanings.

"**Por**+duration" indicates the duration of an action or status. Some speakers (including me) prefer the use of **durante** for this purpose, but **por** is also correct and has been used since the Middle Ages, according to [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/por-con-valor-temporal-3370/). For example:

- No podrá jugar [por/durante] mucho tiempo (*He won't be able to play for a long time*)
- El Zaragoza ha tenido una buena cantera [por/durante] mucho tiempo. (*The Zaragoza team has had a good reserve of young players for a long time*)

"**Para**+duration" is used specifically to mean that a resource or a supply will last for the specified amount of time:

- Los excursionistas se llevaron comida para tres días (*The hikers took with them food for three days*)
- El Zaragoza tiene cantera para mucho tiempo (*Zaragoza's youth team will provide players for a long time*)

Although I have used "mucho tiempo" in most of the examples, this works for any duration expression, such as "cinco años".

Comment: Thanks dear @wimi for your comprehensive explanation. Now I understand it well.